# Could using grid.arrange affect plot output in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, grid

For a function that accepts a data frame, a plot switch value, and bin size vector, I'm trying to create plots for each count-bin and each density-bin size combination for every numerical variable column when a plot switch value of 'grid' is inputted. I have it working that I get individual plots for each combination, but when I tried to put the plots for each numerical variable on a grid and I'm seeing variations in the actual plots even though as far as I can tell I didn't alter the calculations nor the plot commands.

For instance, notice that, even accounting for scale variations, y-density plots are different in the images below. Tried looking at the documentation for grid.arrange and list just to make sure I wasn't missing something, but I still can't figure it out. Did I somehow change the plot command without realizing it?

Tested with:

```
data(diamonds, package = "ggplot2")
test <- diamonds[1:100,]

hstPlts(test,ps='grid') #without grid

hst1(test,ps='grid') #with grid

hstPlts <- function(df,ps = 'off',bnSize=c(30)){

#hstPlts() accepts any data frame and if the ps parameter is “on” or
#“grid”, then plot a pair of blue histograms with a vertical red line at the 
#mean
#for every numerical variable at each number of bins integer specified in  
#the bin
#vector parameter. if the plot switch is set to “grid”, there should be a
#grid for each count-bin combination and a separate grid for
#each density-bin size combination.

#parameters: 

#df : data frame

#ps : plot switch defaulted to 'off' with two additional value options -
#'on' and 'grid'

#bnSize : vector containing numeric values representing number of bins for 
histograms

num_var <- df[sapply(df,is.numeric)] #extract numeric columns

for(i in 1:length(bnSize)){ #iterate through each bin size
    for(j in 1:(ncol(num_var))){ #iterate through each numeric variable
      if(ps=='on' | ps =='grid'){ #conditional for both 'on' and 'grid' 
      #values

          bnWid <- (max(num_var[,j]) - min(num_var[,j]))/bnSize[i] # compute 
              #bin widths
          vrMn <- mean(num_var[[j]]) #compute column means for red line
          mean = sprintf("%8.3f ", vrMn) #set up label for mean line with 
              #formatted decimals
          cntPlt <- ggplot(num_var, aes(x=num_var[,j])) + #plot count   
              #histogram with numeric variable on x-axis
              geom_histogram(colour = "blue", fill = "blue", binwidth =  
              bnWid) +   
              #detail bar fill colors and histogram bin widths

              geom_vline(xintercept = mean(num_var[,j]),colour="red") + 
              #mean line 
              abs(x=colnames(num_var)[j]) #label x-axis
          densPlt <- cntPlt + aes(y = ..density..) + labs(y = "density")  
              #create corresponding density histogram 
          print(cntPlt)
          print(densPlt)
      }

      if(ps == 'grid'){ #conditional for just 'grid' value 

          grdPlt <- ggplot(num_var, aes(x=num_var[,j])) + #create plot for 
              #each count-bin combination and a separate grid for
              #each density-bin size combination
              geom_histogram(colour = "blue", fill = "blue", binwidth = 
              bnWid) +   
              #detail bar fill colors and histogram bin widths

              labs(x=colnames(num_var)[j]) #label x-axis
      print(grdPlt)
      print(grdPlt + aes(y = ..density..) + labs(y = "density")) 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: hstPlts plot y density]

```
hst1 <- function(df,ps = 'off',bsizes=c(30)){

    numvar <- df[sapply(df,is.numeric)] 

    if(ps=='on')  
        for(i in 1:length(bsizes)){ 
            for(j in 1:(ncol(numvar))){ 
                bwidth <- (max(numvar[,j]) - min(numvar[,j]))/bsizes[i] 
                var_mean <- mean(numvar[[j]]) 
                mean = sprintf("%8.3f ", var_mean)
                counts <- ggplot(numvar, aes(x=numvar[,j])) + 
                    geom_histogram(colour = "blue", fill = "blue", binwidth 
                    = bwidth) + 
                    geom_vline(xintercept = mean(numvar[,j]),colour="red") +  
                    labs(x=colnames(numvar)[j]) # Labeling the x axis
                dense <- counts + aes(y = ..density..) + labs(y = "density")
                print(counts)
                print(dense)
            }
        }
    }
    else if(ps == 'grid'){
        for(i in 1:length(bsizes)){
            cntLst <- list()
            denseLst <- list()

            for(j in 1:(ncol(numvar))){
            bwidth <- (max(numvar[,j]) - min(numvar[,j]))/bsizes[i]
            cntGrPlt <- ggplot(numvar, aes(x=numvar[,j])) + 
                geom_histogram(colour = "blue", fill = "blue", binwidth = 
                bwidth) +
                labs(x=colnames(numvar)[j])
            cntLst[[length(cntLst)+1]] <- cntGrPlt
            denseLst[[j]] <- cntGrPlt + aes(y = ..density..) + labs(y = 
            "density")

            }
            grid.arrange(grobs=cntLst,ncol=2)
            grid.arrange(grobs=denseLst,ncol=2)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: hst1 plot y density grid]

Comment: i have no idea what your code is supposed to do, but `aes(x=numvar[,j])` is definitely a bad construct. `aes()` is to map variable names.

Comment: the short answer is no, `grid.arrange` does not (by itself) affect the content of plots.